# Which location is this in Lost Ark?

Tags: lost-ark

I have got a treasure map, but it has no location marked on it.

Where is this location? I have browsed all the islands and continents on https://lostarkmap.com/ and not found it.

[image: map scroll]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This guide](https://www.gosunoob.com/lost-ark/strange-map-treasure-location-solution/) says its in Vern North, specifically Port Krona (the southern part of it).

> First off, the image inside the pattern is clearly a map. Specifically, you need to go to the continent of North Vern, as shown in the image above. Specifically, you have to get to Port Krona. In the south of this region, you’ll find an area called Ruined Port. That’s what the map is depicting.

In the map you linked, I believe this is it:

[image]

You can see the map lines up with the treasure map, only the treasure map is turned slightly:

[image]

Looks like you need to click on this white Tooki Statue with the treasure map in your inventory and you will be given a quest.